# Why does Nginx keep returning 301?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, unicode, nginx

I have an nginx setup that is configured to talk to Unicorn upstream (its a rails app). I've already checked the basics. I know the request is getting to nginx, its mapping to a server_name, it finds the try_files directive, it falls over to the last directive which is @unicorn mapping to a location block. In the location block I have this:

```
location @unicorn {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # this helps Rack set the proper URL scheme for doing HTTPS redirects:
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass http://unicorn_myapp;
      }
```

Then further up the file I have

```
upstream unicorn_myapp {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).
  server unix:/etc/sockets/unicorn.myapp.sock;
}
```

I also have unicorn listening on that same socket. Here's a snippet from my unicorn conf file:

```
# Use at least one worker per core if you're on a dedicated server,
# more will usually help for _short_ waits on databases/caches.
worker_processes 2

# Help ensure your application will always spawn in the symlinked
# "current" directory that Capistrano sets up.
working_directory "/home/deployer/apps/myapp/current"

# listen on both a Unix domain socket
# we use a shorter backlog for quicker failover when busy
listen "/etc/sockets/unicorn.myapp.sock", :backlog => 64
```

I've verified both daemons are running, the socket file exists (e.g. unicorn is listening) and there isn't a permissions problem because that would get logged. Speaking of logs, whenever I request the root directory nginx returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.6
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 21:05:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://myapp.com
```

And this gets logged in nginx's access log:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [30/Mar/2014:17:05:55 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "-"
```

There is *nothing* in Unicorn's log. What could be going on here?

Comment: There should be a file in your application root, config/unicorn.rb, where there is a line, 'listen APP_PATH + "/tmp/pids/.unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64' which describes where the Unicorn socket is located for your nginx server to listen to. Does this match your nginx configuration?

Comment: It does match yeah. I actually posted that bit of the file in my original post if you look closely.

Comment: Unless user "deployer" has write access in /etc/sockets directory (which I seriously doubt), this is absolutely normal. You can check this by going into /etc/sockets and doing one of the following actions: If as u say unicorn.log is empty, just do "touch unicorn.log"... You'll probably see an error. If it's not, then "mv unicorn.log unicorn.log.bak && touch unicorn.log". You'll probably see an error.  I'd suggest you change the location of your socket into a temp folder in your rails folder, as I show you in my previous comment. If not, at least make that file writable to "deployer"

Comment: Deployer does have write access to that directory because I created that directory specifically for this purpose and gave that user write access:
root@myapp-dev:/etc# ls -lad soc*
drwxrwxr-x 2 deployer web 4096 Mar 30 16:45 sockets

srwxrwxrwx  1 deployer deployer    0 Mar 30 16:45 unicorn.myapp.sock

Answer (score 5):

I got it figured it. I actually had force_ssl = true in my production.rb file